# What is the benefit to using await with an async database call

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am just looking at the default MVC5 project and how it uses async in the controllers.

I would like to know what benefit async provides here over simply using synchronous calls:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Disassociate(string loginProvider, string providerKey)
    {
        ManageMessageId? message = null;

        //why use an async database call here with await instead of just using a synchronous one?
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
        }
        else
        {
            message = ManageMessageId.Error;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
    }
```

What am I missing?

Does this provide some kind of performance benefit in the type of wait that will occur here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On the server side (e.g., ASP.NET MVC), any I/O you do (e.g., databases) should be done asynchronously. This frees up the request thread for the time that the I/O is in flight.

So, when the `RemoveLoginAsync` sends its SQL to the database, it returns an incomplete task, and when the request hits the `await`, it returns the request thread to the thread pool. Later, when the DB operation completes, a request thread is taken from the thread pool and used to continue the request.

The end result is scalability, because (in the 99.9% case at least) tasks scale better than threads. However, there isn't a big advantage if your database is just a single server and all requests hit the db, because your scalability bottleneck in that scenario is the db server, not the web server.

Comment: So with an async action it will only occupy a thread while it isnt in a wait? thats pretty cool

Comment: Correct, if all your I/O is `async`, then threads are only used to execute code. It sounds weird, but it's normal to have no threads at all processing a request, whenever the request is awaiting (i.e., asynchronously waiting).